# Cant compare current location to database location android

Tags: android, sqlite, gps

I have a running GPS service but i am unable to compare my current location to locations previously saved in a database. The app is running fine but when i take out the function written in onLocationChange(), out of comments it crashes.

Function is:

```
LocationsDB db = new LocationsDB(this);
     Cursor c = db.getAllLocations();
     c.moveToFirst(); 

     while(c.moveToNext()) {             
        arlist.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("FIELD_LNG")));
        arlistlat.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("FIELD_LAT")));

        }

    for(int i=0;i<arlist.size();i++){
        if(arlist.get(i)==Double.toString(location.getLongitude()) && arlistlat.get(i)==Double.toString(location.getLatitude())){
            Intent myIntent=new Intent(GPSTracker.this,alarm.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use `.equals()` instead of `==` for comparing Strings.

Comment: try to execute the first part of the fonction ( db query and list contruction ) only on the first locationChange

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `==` to compare `String`

instead use `.equal` or `.match`

Something like this :

```
if(arlist.get(i)==Double.toString(location.getLongitude()) && arlistlat.get(i).equal(Double.toString(location.getLatitude()))){
```